# How to use tnsnames.ora in Grails DataSource?

Tags: oracle, grails, datasource, tnsnames

I'm trying to connect to a load-balanced virtual host specified in tnsnames.ora in my Grails application in DataSource.groovy, with no luck - it (obviously) throws an "Unknown Host Specified" exception.

The tnsnames entry looks like this

```
someServiceName =
 (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
   (FAILOVER=ON)
   (LOAD_BALANCE=ON)
   (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS_LIST =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = someServerName1)(PORT = 1521))
     )
     (CONNECT_DATA =
       (SERVICE_NAME = someServiceName1)
     )
   )
   (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS_LIST =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = someServerName2)(PORT = 1521))
     )
     (CONNECT_DATA =
       (SERVICE_NAME = someServiceName2)
     )
   )
 )
```

I can connect to one of the services (someServiceName1 & someServiceName2) by simply setting the values in DataSource.groovy in the usual way, but I don't know how to connect to the load-balanced virtual host.
I've searched around for using tnsnames.ora in Grails but I can't seem to find a particularly "groovy" way of making this work. Any pointers will be appreciated.

P.S. I would prefer a solution where I would still be able to inject the dataSource into my controllers etc.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to configure a single service with multiple addresses. Then you have to set your datasource URL string to something like this (without the newlines of course):

```
jdbc:oracle:thin@(DESCRIPTION=
   (LOAD_BALANCE=on)
   (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=someServerName1) (PORT=1521))
   (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=someServerName2) (PORT=1521))
   (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=theOnlyServiceName)))
```

Look [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/e10788/rac.htm) and [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/A89868_02/haconfig.htm) for references.

Comment: Thanks for the references. The included sample didn't work for me but the references proved to hold the specific connection string I needed to set.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
jdbc:oracle:oci:@someServiceName
```

I use this, notice it's `oci`, not thin. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this issue, here's what fixed it for me:

url='jdbc:oracle:thin:@servername:PORT/servicename'

It was the forward slash between the port and the service name that tripped me up. If you use a colon there, it reads it as a SID instead of a service name.

Good luck!